# htaccess rewrite folder with a question mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to rewrite my folder with a question mark. Is this possible?

It would look like this:

My link now:
http://domain.com/folder/page

Wanted result:
http://domain.com/?page

or (in the worst case):
http://domain.com/page

BTW, I am using this code in my htaccess to access .php files without .php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^folder/ folder%{REQUEST_UEI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work for me. I've tried adding .php after 1 and after $, but it still does nothing. I am also using this to access .php files without .php thats why I tried to add .php: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
`. I tried to delete the code I use too, but still nothing.

Comment: Can you edit your question and place your current rules since ordering is pretty critical here and one rule might conflict with others.

Comment: just tried it and still nothing. I've tried even changing + with * and ?mark with folder, but still can't see the result.:/

Comment: which URL did you use to test this? Also what is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: I use http://domain.com/?post and I still on the main page of my domain. And when I tried http://domain.com/folder/post it looks the same as without the code in htaccess. Location of htaccess is the main folder of domain.

Comment: `domain.com/?post` will remain as is since there is no redirection rule. However `domain.com/folder/post` will internally rewrite to and show content of `domain.com/?post`.

Comment: oh.. well I need by contraries. would be this possible to make domain.com/post (without mark) to show content of domain.com/folder/post?

Comment: updated `domain.com/post` takes to `domain.com/folder`

Comment: Do you mean that browser URL is changing to `domain.com/folder/post`?

Comment: None of these rules are chancing the URL if you notice (there is no R flag). Do you have any other rules not shown OR any other .htaccess in your system? Also try this in a new browser.